# Stripe API payout

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

I have an application where a user can buy and sell my ERC20 token with USD. I have finished the buying part successfully with stripe checkout. Now I am trying to implement user selling the ERC20 token. When the user sells the token he will receive USD. I want to do this with Stripe payout API. The process is when the user try to sell the token he will have to either give his stripe account ID and if the user doen't have a stripe account I will get the sellers bank route number , bank account number and email Id and create a stripe account for the seller using stripe.accounts.create . I am trying all this in the test mode. So what I want to know is
1.I need a stripe account Id for testing where do I get it .
2.when I try to create a new account with test bank account, bank route number and emailID I get an error saying that I should register for Stripe connect. How do I do that.
3. Or is there an other way that is better suited for my requirement in StripeAPI.

This is my frontend code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

export default function PayoutPage() {
  const [recipientId, setRecipientId] = useState('');
  const [routingNumber, setRoutingNumber] = useState('');
  const [accountNumber, setAccountNumber] = useState('');
  const [numberOfTokens, setNumberOfTokens]=useState()
  const [emailId , setEmailId] = useState('')

  const handlePayout = async () => {
    const stripe = await stripePromise;
    const total = await totalCalcualtion()
    const ttl = numberOfTokens * total;
    const totalPayout =Math.round(ttl*100)
    console.log(totalPayout)

    let payoutData = {
      amount: totalPayout,
    };

    if (recipientId) {
      payoutData.recipientId = recipientId;
    } else {
      payoutData.routingNumber = routingNumber;
      payoutData.accountNumber = accountNumber;
      payoutData.emailId = emailId;
    }

    const response = await fetch('/api/blockchain/sell_token_usd', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payoutData)
    });

    const { sessionId } = await response.json();
    console.log("sessionId", sessionId)
    if (sessionId) {
      // Redirect the user to the Stripe Checkout page
      const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId
      });

      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  };

  const totalCalcualtion=()=>{
    const pricePerToken = 1.68;
    const tokenfee = 3;
    const total = pricePerToken - (pricePerToken* (tokenfee/100));
    return total
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Payout Page</h1>

      <div>
        <label>Number of tokens </label>
        <input type='text' onChange={(e)=>setNumberOfTokens(e.target.value)}></input><br/><br/>
        <label>Stripe Account ID:</label>
        <input type="text" value={recipientId} onChange={(e) => setRecipientId(e.target.value)} />
      </div><br/>
        <h3>Don't have a stripe account enter the following details</h3><br/>
      {!recipientId && (
        <div>
          <label>Bank Routing Number:</label>
          <input type="text"  onChange={(e) => setRoutingNumber(e.target.value)} />

          <label>Bank Account Number:</label>
          <input type="text" value={accountNumber} onChange={(e) => setAccountNumber(e.target.value)} />

          <label>Email Id:</label>
          <input type="text" value={emailId} onChange={(e) => setEmailId(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
      )}

      <button onClick={handlePayout}>Initiate Payout</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Backend :

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: '2020-08-27'
});

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const { amount, recipientId, routingNumber, accountNumber,emailId } = req.body;

      let recipientAccountId;

      if (recipientId) {
        recipientAccountId = recipientId;
      } else {
        // Create a Custom account for the recipient
        const customAccount = await stripe.accounts.create({
          type: 'custom',
          country: 'US', 
          email: emailId 
        });

        recipientAccountId = customAccount.id;

        // Add the recipient's bank account details
        await stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(recipientAccountId, {
          external_account: {
            object: 'bank_account',
            country: 'US', 
            currency: 'usd',
            routing_number: routingNumber,
            account_number: accountNumber
          }
        });
      }

      // Create a payout to the recipient's account
      const payout = await stripe.payouts.create({
        amount,
        currency: 'usd',
        method: 'standard',
        destination: recipientAccountId
      });

      // Create a session ID to pass back to the client
      const sessionId = payout.id;

      res.status(200).json({ sessionId });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while initiating the payout.' });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Stripe Account, you have two modes: Test and Live. You can do all your tests in your test Mode:

https://stripe.com/docs/test-mode

For Connect you can also do tests in the Test Mode of your Stripe Account:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing

For example for payouts you can add one of these test bank account or debit card numbers:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#payouts

Comment: Thank you. Now I have activated the stripe connect and I used a test bank routing number and bank account number to create a new account . Now I am getting a error                            "No such external account: 'acct_1N1nX6Gdo4glIska'" .